# How to build ExtJS project with Maven

Tags: java, maven, extjs

I tried to configure [sencha cmd](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/) in Maven using the mojo plugin. Maven configuration looks like below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sencha-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Set path to your Sencha Cmd executable-->
                <executable>${env.SENCHA_CMD}</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-sdk</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</argument>
                    <argument>app</argument>
                    <argument>build</argument>
                    <argument>--clean</argument>
                    <argument>--environment</argument>
                    <argument>${sencha.env}</argument>
                    <argument>--destination</argument>
                    <argument>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/build</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My project structure looks:[image]

I set environment variable `SENCHA_CMD=C:\Users\yura\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.1.0.26`(in my case I'm using Windows OS).
When i try to execute the `mvn:compile` command i get the error:

> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (sencha-compile) on project vehicle-store: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "C:\Users\yura\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.1.0.26" (in directory "C:\Users\yura\Dropbox\Programming\Java\Projects\IntelliJ\VehicleStore"): CreateProcess error=5, Îòêàçàíî â äîñòóïå -> [Help 1]
>       org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3.2:exec (sencha-compile) on project vehicle-store: Command execution failed.
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
>           at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
>           at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>           at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
>       Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command execution failed.
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:308)
>           at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>           ... 20 more
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\yura\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.1.0.26" (in directory "C:\Users\yura\Dropbox\Programming\Java\Projects\IntelliJ\VehicleStore"): CreateProcess error=5, Îòêàçàíî â äîñòóïå
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
>           at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
>           at org.apache.commons.exec.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Java13CommandLauncher.java:58)
>           at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.launch(DefaultExecutor.java:277)
>           at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:334)
>           at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:164)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine(ExecMojo.java:746)
>           at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute(ExecMojo.java:292)
>           ... 22 more
>       Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=5, Îòêàçàíî â äîñòóïå
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:385)
>           at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
>           at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
>           ... 29 more

How can I fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

In fact this isn't a direct answer, but maybe it gives you an idea. The idea is, that behind the IOException there's a helpful error message in your language. According to what I saw I assumed, that you're from Urkaine and use Windows. So I looked up the default windows code page for Ukraine. that brought me [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251). As java is based on Unicode and Unicode is based on ISO8859-1 I used this little programm to re-encode the message.

```
    byte[] bytes = "Îòêàçàíî â äîñòóïå".getBytes("ISO8859-1");
    System.out.println(new String(bytes, "Windows-1251"));
```

the result was:

```
Отказано в доступе
```

Which Google translates to me as access denied.

However in addition to this very interesting encoding stuff I see the message

> Cannot run program "C:\Users\yura\bin\Sencha\Cmd\5.1.0.26"

and this rather looks like a directory, than like a command. Could this value be wrong?

Comment: You are [Columbo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbo) (in good sense). You are right, this value is wrong. And you give me idea what is wrong. Thanks for reply.

Comment: I changed path to sencha cmd in maven:`<executable>${env.SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0}/sencha.exe</executable>`, path to ext-js`<argument>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/ext</argument>` and set my user account as administrator in Windows(because i got the error: access denied). After all that i got new error: `[ERR] Please ensure this command was executed from a valid application directory
[ERR] Unable to locate 'app.dir' config property from sencha.cfg`. I use version of ext-js 5.0.1.1255 and version of cmd 5.0.1.231. Maybe someone has some ideas how can i fix last one?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error as follows: downloaded new version of `ExtJS(5.1.0.107)` and `sencha cmd(5.1.0.26)`. Then I change `sencha cmd configuration` in `maven`:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.2</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>sencha-compile</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <!-- Set path to your Sencha Cmd executable-->
            <executable>${env.SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0}/sencha.exe</executable>
            <arguments>
                <!-- Sets the directory from which commands should execute using command -->
                <argument>--cwd</argument>
                <argument>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</argument>
                <argument>app</argument>
                <argument>build</argument>
                <argument>--clean</argument>
                <argument>--environment</argument>
                <argument>${sencha.env}</argument>
                <argument>--destination</argument>
                <argument>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/build</argument>
            </arguments>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Important:  **Do NOT** specify the `-sdk` parameter for `sencha app` commands. For details see [here](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/extjs/cmd_app.html). Instead of that, I set the directory from which commands should execute using `--cwd` command.